# htaccess rewriteRule not displaying new url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My question is how to get the URL in the RewriteRule to display when I click the link (domain.com/?brandID=1&name=Beretta).

My tests make me believe it might have something to do with index.php, but maybe not. My script is triggered by the GET variable being set, and queries the DB and includes the page that displays the results (and the "ugly" url).

Here's the .htaccess code:

```
# Rewrite for ?brandID=1&name=Name
RewriteRule ^pistol-brand/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) ?brandID=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

I want to replace domain.com/?brandID=1&name=Beretta with domain.com/pistol-brand/1/beretta

The code above displays the "ugly" url, but when I change the url to what the RewriteRule states (domain.com/pistol-brand/1/beretta), the page works.

How do I get the "new" url to display when the link is clicked?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: `?brandID=$1&name=$2` is not a valid URL, you cannot rewrite to that.

Comment: I also failed using:  RewriteRule ^pistol-brand/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) index.php?brandID=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: I am not sure if you understood how url rewriting works. Don't get this wrong! Just trying to prevent a lot of frustration here. The above rule certainly will not do anything if you click a link like that: `http :// domain.com/?brandID=1&name=Beretta`. You need to have a link like this instead and click it: `http :// domain.com/pistol-brand/1/beretta`. Then indeed the url rewriting should _internally_ rewrite that request so that your scripts can process it. So there is no need to "change" the url shown in the browser, since it already shows the "pretty" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more to redirect the ugly url to sef format

```
##1)Redirect /?brandID=foo&name=bar to //pistol-brand/foo/bar##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?brandID=([^&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pistol-brand/%1/%2? [L,R]
##2)Rewrite  /pistol-brand/foo/bar to /?brandID=foo&name=bar##
    RewriteRule ^pistol-brand/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) ?brandID=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this solution. It works. I hope to figure out how and why. Thank you.